# How can I sum "Expr" in bottom of the table in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I'm doing such a thing;

```
=Sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) - Sum(Fields!IND.Value)
```

In cells, so this is end up with expresion "<<'Expr'>>", that means I'm finding net worth price - discount for each saled products, after that I want to sum all of those product's sales on bottom, like

```
=Sum(Sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) - Sum(Fields!IND.Value) )
```

Any chance for that? I also tried like;

```
=Sum(ReportItems!TOTALBOX.Value)
```

But not work either.

**Edit;**
[image]

I'm doing something like that but on final, I want to sum those values which "<>" created.

Thx.

Comment: If you made a table with a group or detail and you want a total outside the detail or group, you can use the same formula `=Sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) - Sum(Fields!IND.Value)` and it will work due to being outside the grouping scope.

Comment: @HannoverFist Thx for your comment, I add picture to my question above, so I already have a grouping for customers. (if I understand your advice corrently)

Answer (score 0):

Since your data is in a Column Group (by **[DEFINITION_]** - the 3 columns with the line above them) you can create a total column using the same formula. The Total will SUM all the different DEFINITION groups for each **[NAME]** group.

You can add a column Outside the group and create your total column with the same formula

```
=Sum(Fields!TOTAL.Value) - Sum(Fields!IND.Value)
```

[image]

If you created everything correctly (and you're lucky), SSRS might be able to create the Total for you by right clicking on the cell and **Add Total**.

[image]